# Check if more than two arrays have same data

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say all these all have the same data in common.

How would I do this in this multidimensional array.

I'm basically trying to find all the same elements using

```
array_intersect($array,$array);
```

but I cannot figure out what I should be doing in order to do that.

```
array(14) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "0.1"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "0.2"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "0.3"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "0.4"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "0.1"
    [5]=>
    string(5) "0.2"
    [6]=>
    string(5) "0.3"
    [7]=>
    string(5) "0.4"
    [8]=>
    string(5) "0.2"
    [9]=>
    string(5) "0.3"
    [10]=>
    string(5) "0.4"
    [11]=>
    string(5) "0.1"
    [12]=>
    string(5) "0.2"
    [13]=>
    string(5) "0.3"
  }
```

Comment: array(14) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "0.1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "0.2"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "0.3"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "0.4"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "0.1"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "0.2"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "0.3"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "0.4"
  [8]=>
  string(5) "0.2"
  [9]=>
  string(5) "0.3"
  [10]=>
  string(5) "0.4"
  [11]=>
  string(5) "0.1"
  [12]=>
  string(5) "0.2"
  [13]=>
  string(5) "0.3"
}

i'm trying to find out what is common with all these. This is what i get after doing var_dump($compare)

Comment: OK, the input is entirely different from the input in the first question... Deleting my answer ;) With the current input you can't do zilch, as there's no 2nd datapoint to check. The most you can get out of the input stated now is `array_count_values`, but that still doesn't tell you about what data points have in common.

Comment: Lets say I know there is 4 datasets I can see how many time that value occurs 4 times. So would array_count_values accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are exactly looking for:

```
$i=0;  // index of the orginal array
$common = array_reduce($array, function ($c, $v) use (&$i) {
    foreach ($v['data'] as $nb) {
        $c[$nb][] = $i; // store the index for the current number
    }
    $i++; // next index
    return $c;
}, array());

// remove the unique values
$common = array_filter($common, function($item) { return count($item)>1; });

// sort by decreasing number of indexes
uasort($common, function ($a, $b) {return count($b) - count($a);});

print_r($common);
```

This will produce an associative array with the common number as key, and an array with the indexes of the original array as value:

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )
    [4] => Array (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3
        )
    [6] => Array (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )
    [3] => Array (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )
)
```